# How to understand this snippet of Kotlin code?

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I come from Java and I'm following a tutorial online regarding using the `Volley` library to make web requests in Android.

The instructor created the request variable like this:

```
val registerRequest = object : StringRequest(Method.POST, URL_REGISTER, Response.Listener {
            println(it) // will print the response
            complete(true)
        }, Response.ErrorListener {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Could not register user: $it")
            complete(false)
        }) {
            override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }

            override fun getBody(): ByteArray {
                return requestBody.toByteArray()
            }
        }
```

I understand that he's creating a `registerRequest` variable of type `StringRequest`. But what I don't understand is why he prefixed `StringRequest` with `object :` here.

Also I understand that `StringRequest` constructor takes in an `Int, String, Lambda, Lambda`. After that it becomes confusing to me because the developer was able to declare some `override` methods after the constructor closes. Why did they do this? From what I can tell, this is similar to subclassing StringRequest, then writing the override methods there? Am I right?

Coming from Java, this way of writing code is quite unusual to me.

Comment: it's an anonymous class, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions. In java you would have seen `= new StringRequest()...`

Comment: @TimCastelijns Ah that makes sense. Didn't know that you could do this stuff in Kotlin as it's a very different practice from Java. Thanks!

Comment: You need to read and understand a breadth of Kotlin before dropping into reading random code.  Make sure you have wall to wall coverage over Kotlin otherwise you'll keep finding mysterious code that you do not have the toolkit to decipher.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am actually taking a Kotlin online course right now to get more comfortable with the language.